# How to attach more than Python files from Google Drive into one notebook in colab?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pycharm, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I wrote this code in colab to get data from Google Drive but give me error

```
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':"your_file_ID"})   # replace the id with id of file you want to access

downloaded.GetContentFile('your_file_name.csv')        # replace the file name with your file
```

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pydrive/files.py in FetchMetadata(self, fields, fetch_all)
    242         self.UpdateMetadata(metadata)
    243     else:
--> 244       raise FileNotUploadedError()
    245 
    246   @LoadMetadata

FileNotUploadedError:
```

Comment: Colab has an option of `Mount Drive` in the left menu section. After that you can just go the file which you want to get and then click on it's options and copy the path. In case you want to use someone's else drive then you can make a `shortcut to drive` of that respective folder and then it will appear as your folder in your drive.

Comment: Although the comment might not solve your current problem of `file not found` but it will most of your hassles.

Comment: I already solve this problem and find good solution to the problem i upload the code in agit repository   https://github.com/basmahajjaj/Importing_pythonFiles_fromdrive_tocolab